# Conditional formatting with data validations

Tags: validation, checkbox, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Spreadsheets I have a column of various dates (these are employee's start dates). I want the cells to be highlighted when today's day is within a week of these employee start dates.

I have already been playing with `=(B4-TODAY())>7` but this seems to highlight *all* the past dates.

If this is not possible, just being able to highlight this month's dates is fine (which is easy to do in Excel but can't seem to figure out in Google Spreadsheets).

Then, once this has been done, I have another column with a drop box selection with `DONE`, and, `PENDING`.

I would like to conditionally format it so that when `DONE` is clicked, the highlighted start dates in this month (or 7 days before the day) are highlighted in a different colour.

So it can easily be seen that in 1 week employees are coming, and when done is clicked, we can see their administrative stuff has been dealt with.

Comment: You should add the tag : Google-Spreadsheet. It might help you grab so more covering.

Comment: Thank you, have made the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `=B1="DONE"` for the alternative colour and for the +/-7 days:

```
=and(A1<today()+7,A1>today()-7)
```

in that order.

[image: SO24916720 first example]

=and(…) is used in one of the formulae because the relevant condition is for a bounded range. When I enter =today() in Google Spreadsheets and change that cell’s format to Number I see `41,845.00`. Since one week either side makes up the ‘band’ to which attention is to be drawn the relevant values for CF are everything from and including `41,838` to `41,852`.

But for display purposes I switch to one day either side, rather than one week, and leave off 41840 throughout, so today becomes represented by `5`, and the reduced range of interest therefore `4` to `6` (both inclusive). Of all the possibilities, any value up to and including `3`, and `7` or greater, is to be ignored for CF:

[image: SO24916720 second example]

The range of interest is everything less than `7` (green) *that is also* more than `3` (blue):

[image: SO24916720 third example]

For “that is also” Google prefers `and`. In case of any remaining uncertainty creating your own example with a week either side of `41845` etc may help.

Comment: You are wonderful - Thank you!

P.S. I have been wondering what the function of 'and' is in the beginning?

Comment: Sorry for not leaving a comment - all the info is very much appreciated! TY